# Does an SQL query like this exist?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I found something on google which said MySql allows me to do something like this:

```
$sql = "IF(EXISTS(SELECT api_key, username FROM credentials WHERE id = 0)) 
    THEN UPDATE credentials SET api_key = ?, username = ? WHERE id = 0 ELSE
    INSERT INTO credentials (api_key, username) VALUES (?, ?) END IF";
```

This is the function the query makes part of:

```
protected function store_credentials($config_file_path = 'envato_credentials_config.json') {
    $credentials_config = $this->get_envato_config($config_file_path);
    $sql = "INSERT INTO credentials (api_key, username, last_update) VALUES (?, ?, NOW()) ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE api_key = values(api_key), username = values(username), last_update = values(last_update)";
    if ($stmt = $this->connect->prepare($sql)) {
        $stmt->bind_param('ss', $credentials_config['API'], $credentials_config['User']);
        $stmt->execute();
        $stmt->close();
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Can I do something like that ? And am I understanding the statement clearly, if no values are found inside those two columns then new values will be inserted, else it will only update ?

Comment: This is often called an UPSERT

Comment: I see, so it is correct from a syntax point of view, but is it the simplest one ?

Comment: Exists,but not as exactly as you posted.give us the full query

Comment: That is why I asked, to be sure I'm not doing a stupid thing :) Anyway, there's an answer which helps me more than what I added :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use MySQL's [on duplicate key syntax](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/insert-on-duplicate.html):

```
INSERT INTO credentials (api_key, username) VALUES (?, ?)
    ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE api_key = values(api_key), username = values(username);
```

Comment: by `KEY` here do you mean the primary key?

Comment: Any UNIQUE index or PRIMARY KEY can trigger the `on duplicate key` clause

Comment: So this statement would do what I want ?

Comment: I sure hope so or I wouldn't have posted it ;)  But there's no substitute for testing.

Comment: I'm just testing right now :) If it does work, I would like to ask if I can combine it with something else :)

Comment: This works, just that I get duplicate entries :| Perhaps is because it runs twice. I'll check that. What I wanted to ask is, if I have another column `last_update` which is datetime, can I run the update statement if there's more than two hours since last update ? For example I'm running a query like this to do that, without the insert if the table is empty: `SELECT IF(TIMEDIFF(NOW(), last_update) > '02:00:00', 1, 0) FROM ".$table." LIMIT 1`;  could I combine that with this statement, what I'm saying is,insert into table if it's empty and only update if that two hours passed since last update?

Comment: You could probably add `, last_update = IF(TIMEDIFF(NOW(), last_update) > '02:00:00', last_update, now())` to the update clause

Comment: Should I ask another question to be more specific and with a better description ? Because I don't want to update only last_update. What I want is to update all the fields only if the time diff is greater than 2 hours ( which I can check against that last_update field ) .

Comment: @Andomar - there seems to be a problem with the `INSERT INTO credentials (api_key, username) VALUES (?, ?)
    ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE api_key = values(api_key), username = values(username);`, each time it runs, it makes duplicate entries, and even though, as you said, it should only update if the values are encountered, it makes another two entries, and so on... I've updated my question with the whole query I'm running and the manner I'm doing it.

Comment: @Roland I have had enough troubles using update on duplicate key feature of mysql, its buggy. In fact a known bug which is corrected from a certain version of MySQL only. I used version 5 then. Not sure if that exactly is causing you trouble..

Comment: @Roland though this is not a solution to your problem I believe, you need not have to update the primary key field in update statement. You can just omit it.

Answer (score 2):

mysql has REPLACE syntax which does this. If record exists it updates it (actually deletes old row and inserts new row) otherwise inserts.

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/replace.html

```
13.2.7. REPLACE Syntax
REPLACE [LOW_PRIORITY | DELAYED]
    [INTO] tbl_name [(col_name,...)]
    {VALUES | VALUE} ({expr | DEFAULT},...),(...),...
Or:

REPLACE [LOW_PRIORITY | DELAYED]
    [INTO] tbl_name
    SET col_name={expr | DEFAULT}, ...
Or:

REPLACE [LOW_PRIORITY | DELAYED]
    [INTO] tbl_name [(col_name,...)]
    SELECT ...
REPLACE works exactly like INSERT, except that if an old row in the table has the same value as a new row for a PRIMARY KEY or a UNIQUE index, the old row is deleted before the new row is inserted. See Section 13.2.5, “INSERT Syntax”.

REPLACE is a MySQL extension to the SQL standard. It either inserts, or deletes and inserts. For another MySQL extension to standard SQL—that either inserts or updates—see Section 13.2.5.3, “INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE Syntax”.

Note that unless the table has a PRIMARY KEY or UNIQUE index, using a REPLACE statement makes no sense. It becomes equivalent to INSERT, because there is no index to be used to determine whether a new row duplicates another.

Values for all columns are taken from the values specified in the REPLACE statement. Any missing columns are set to their default values, just as happens for INSERT. You cannot refer to values from the current row and use them in the new row. If you use an assignment such as SET col_name = col_name + 1, the reference to the column name on the right hand side is treated as DEFAULT(col_name), so the assignment is equivalent to SET col_name = DEFAULT(col_name) + 1.

To use REPLACE, you must have both the INSERT and DELETE privileges for the table.
```

Comment: This should work but be aware that this does delete! For a column with an `on delete cascade` foreign key, `replace` would cause deletes in the referencing table